# React Router does not recognize direct address line changing in laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-router

I use React Router and Laravel. When I navigate throught Link elements all OK, but when I change browser address line to manually show another component Laravel shows it defalt 404 page.

This is default web.php content, in welcome.blade.php I inlcude js/app.js file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});
```

This is my App.js content:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Signin from "../../containers/Signin";
import Signup from "../../containers/Signup";
import Error from "../../containers/Error";
import Courses from "../../containers/Courses";
import Course from "../../containers/Course";
import Quiz from "../../containers/Quiz";
import Header from "../Header";
import "./App.css";
import Library from "../../containers/Library";
import QuizResults from "../../containers/QuizResults";
import Main from "../Main";
import StudentsList from "../../containers/StudentsList";


function App()
{
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Header isLogged={false}/>

      <Switch>

        <Route exact path='/' component={Signin} />
        <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />


        <Main>
          <Route path='/courses' component={Courses} />
          <Route path='/course/:id' component={Course} exact/>
          <Route path='/quiz' component={Quiz} />
          <Route path='/library' component={Library} />
          <Route path='/quiz-results' component={QuizResults} />
          <Route path='/students' component={StudentsList} />
        </Main>

        <Route component={Error} />

      </Switch>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**app.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import './index.css';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

So, how to force React Router react on direct browser address line change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as your working with SPA so you need to configure your `web.php` like this

```php
Route::any('{all}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})
->where('all', '^(?!api).*$')
->where('all', '^(?!storage).*$');
```

then react router will catch all routes

and here `api` and `storage` routes is exclude from catch so you can use storage files and api to make call api