# Vue router is not routing

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

When directing to '/' the "mainapp im here" message is showing but the routing
to homepage is not happening , below is my code , this is my first time using Vue
and im trying to work with it, the problem it's not routing note that
it's accessing the router.js

----- web.php

// Client Routes

```
Route::get('/', 'Client\HomeController@index');
```

----- HomeController.php

```
  <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Client;

   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   use App\Package;

   class HomeController extends Controller
   {

   public function index()
   {
    return view('client.home.index');
   }
   }
```

----- Index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
   
    <title>Laravel</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

     <mainapp> </mainapp>

    </div>
</body>

<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

----- mainapp.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>mainapp im heree</h1>
   <router-view> </router-view>
</div>
</template>
```

----- Router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(Router)

import homePage from './components/pages/homePage.vue'

const routes =[ 
        {
            path:'/',
            component: homePage
        }           
       ]

export default new Router ({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
           })
```

-----app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
import router from './router'

Vue.component('mainapp', require('./components/mainapp.vue').default);
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
router
       })
```

-----Homepage.vue

```
<template>


<div>
<h1>hello</h1>

</div>


</template>
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64643273/react-router-does-not-recognize-direct-address-line-changing-in-laravel/64643311#64643311 for SPA

Comment: yeah, unfortunately the vue router [documentation for history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) doesn't include help for configuring your particular server environment